# Is there a way in a listbox text to make the number increment?

Tags: c#, listbox

Trying to make the value of a penny double day after day. My math is correct and displays like it should except for the text in the list box.

Have already tried to increase with an integer variable

```
        pennyDouble = 0.01;
        daysInteger = 1;

        do
        {
            millionaireListBox.Items.Add("The value after 1 day(s) is: $"  + pennyDouble);
            pennyDouble = (2 * pennyDouble);
            daysInteger += 1;
        }while(condition);
```

So in the list box I want it to say,

> "The value after 1 day(s) is: $0.01"

with the day part increasing. So,

> "The value after 2 day(s) is: $0.02"

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your string which you are adding to `millionaireListBox`. It should be

```
millionaireListBox.Items.Add($"The value after {daysInteger} day(s) is: $ {pennyDouble}");
                                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^ Instead of constant 1, you need variable.
```

Even after `daysInteger` increment, you are using 1 in string. This constant 1 is adding same value to `millionaireListBox` everytime.

You need incremental days in `ListBox`, so use variable `daysInteger` instead of constant 1.